# Conda environment.yml without Conda

Tags: python, django, pip, conda

Currently, I am trying to dockerize a Django app that the last developer developed using conda.
And the required libs are listed in a file called environment.txt .

Is it possible to install the dependencies without having conda installed since I don't want to add conda in my app stack?

I've read that you cant just copy and paste the dependencies into a requirements.txt file and install it with pip because that would install a lot of conda dependencies together, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

pip should have the same packages available that conda has, so using pip to install should work without any conda dependency. Some of the entries in the requirements.txt file may need to be installed separately, using this format:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```